# ValidationMessageFor is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, html, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

My webpage validation is working only at local server.

Web.Config include

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

View.cshtml include

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewName", "ControllerName")) {

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, null, new { @class = "validation" })

<input type="submit" value="log in" class="submitbutton" />

}
```

I'm using Linq to SQL. File include

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

and fields similar to this one

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "* error message")]
    public string email
            ...
```

When i'm debbuging from Visual Web Developer Express 2010 validation work perfectly.

Problem is that when i've uploaded files to outside hosting place validation is not working at all. Nothing happens after i'm clicking submit button. I have tried many solutions and nothing helped me.

Comment: Likely your scripts are not found. You should not be referencing your scripts like that. Can you verify if the script src is correct once deployed?

Comment: I have checked page source and link to scripts seems ok. I can see whole files text after cliking link.

Comment: You missed the close tag in your 3rd script !!

Comment: I have noticed it, fixed it and still not working.

Comment: Open Javascript console in your browser and check for errors.

Comment: GET http://domainadress/Scripts/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help you? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382031/746045](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382031/746045)

Answer (score 0):

You missed `@Url.Content` for the script files src

Try this instead of your script file on header side. 
 **use tilled characters**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Edit** : You missed the closed tag on you last script

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascri**pt"</**script>
```

It's just path or any simple mistaken problem , check the path on server

**Other  solution :**

1) Check your css path and deployed the all files on server ?

2)Check the Jquery library was if already added in your layout page .

3) Did you call the css file in your page or layout ?

4) please check your server has  deployed all scripts and css  and configured matched webconfig file with local !

Comment: I have tried                                                  <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript)"></script> and still not working

Comment: remove ../.. in all scripts !

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, now i found one another problem , see my edited answer one more time !!

Comment: I have noticed it, fixed closing tag and still not working. How to check path on server?

Comment: CSS files seems ok. My layout work perfectly. All needed files are on server and layout page doesn't have any JQuery libraries.

Comment: where you call your css file ?

Comment: I have tried both calls. First in view page and then in layoutpage. Not working to both solutions. I have scripts called in view page atm.

Comment: Sorry ! I gave my all ideas but the issue was not fixed yet . hmm . don't worry i think it's any minor issue !!  please check your server has deployed  all scripts and css  and configured matched webconfig with local !

Comment: Scripts, css and webconfigs files are all the same and there is no missing files.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that problem is somewhere else. I have tried to validate my own model and it is working normally. The only problem left that website using validating in Linq to SQL file works only in local server.